# GitHub - как добавить файл/папку?

Tags: git, github

По стандартным примерам самого GitHub'a получилось создать файл `README.md`.

Как в этом же репозитории, там же где и `README.md` создать еще один файл/папку? Я создал файл в этом репозитории (`test`) напр. `style.css` у себя на машине, выполнил команду `git add style.css`, но файл не добавился удаленно.

Как это свести воедино? Что сделать, чтобы мой `style.css` появился в репозитории `test` на GitHub?

Comment: Вот еще отличный материал и на русском языке. [GitHowTo](http://githowto.com/ru).

Comment: А почему не через `git`?

Comment: Предположим что лень. Интересен чисто теоретико-практический вопрос)

Comment: Да, и ещё, на битбакэте есть аналог gh-pages, и как там дело с загрузкой?

Comment: На bitbucket можно создать сайтик с адресом <имя_пользователя>.bitbucket.org, но все страницы нужно будет верстать руками (т.е. никаких шаблонов, никакого тебе markdown, только html, css, js). Загрузка файлов - через mercurial или git (смотря какого типа репозиторий был создан). Инструкция (неофициальная): http://pages.bitbucket.org/

Comment: т.е. на битбакете нет возможности создания и редактирования текстовых(html css) файлов через браузер? только через установку утилит?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
git commit
git push
```

---

Вообще, начиная работать с какой-либо системой контроля версий, имеет смысл прочитать `Quick Start Guide` для ознакомления в целом и для того, чтобы узнать об основных функциях.

*Для случая `git` можно начать с [**Git Howto**](http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2008/03/25/got-git-howto-git-and-github/) и дальше уже пробежаться по референсам.*

[image: git commands]

Answer (score 5):

Текстовые файлы можно создавать через + рядом с именем текущей папки.

Бинарные закачивать нельзя (по крайней мере в текущей версии интерфейса).

**UP:** Github теперь [поддерживает загрузку любых файлов](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/) напрямую через интерфейс.

Comment: про текстовые понятно. интересовало именно загрузка картинок без установки доп. утилит.

Comment: Этот ответ был изначально дан к вопросу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464690/181472

Answer (score 5):

Файлы, чьё содержимое открывается в текстовых редакторах, можно создавать через веб-панель. Входим на свой репозиторий ( YourName/YourRepository.github.io ) — «New File» — копируем/вставляем содержимое файла — «Commit new file». Для создания папки необходимо создать файл, который будет в ней содержаться, см. гифку.

[image: Создание папок через веб-интерфейс на Гитхабе]

Буквально на днях в Github появилась возможность загрузки (не создания) файлов через веб-интерфейс. При заходе на свой репозиторий всё сразу будет видно: нужно перенести файлы в область большого прямоугольника, где написано «File uploading is now available» (или лишний раз нажать «Upload files» и перенести).

В первые дни после введения веб-загрузки имена изображений менялись на default.jpg (default.png, default.jpeg), но сейчас вроде бы с багом покончено: имена, заданные пользователем, остаются.

После внесения изменений в вебе не забывайте переносить их из репозитория на компьютер командой `git pull`. Спасибо.

[image: Загрузка на Github через Web]

Answer (score 4):

Стоит также упомянуть о возможности создания и редактирования файлов на GitHub посредством сервиса [prose.io](http://prose.io) . Преимущества:

1. Русский язык интерфейса. Для переключения наведите курсор мыши под самую левую вкладку окна браузера, должно высветиться меню:
   [image: Переключение на русский язык]
   «Language» — выбираем русский
2. Редактирование сразу при открытии файла. Не нужно дополнительно нажимать на кнопки вроде «Редактировать» или «Edit».
3. Поиск при редактировании фрагмента текста с помощью `Ctrl` + `F` работает по всему файлу. В веб-редакторе ГитХаба так позволено искать только по 30 видимым в форме ввода и редактирования текста строкам.
4. Поддержка Markdown — той самой удобной разметки, что используется на Stack Overflow. Справка о ней отображается при нажатии на вопросительный знак:
   [image: Справка о Markdown на prose.io]
   Если Вы не создаёте новый и не редактируете .md-файл, меню над формой ввода текста не появится, но о разметке всегда можно почитать, например, [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/editing-help).
5. Быстрое восстановление недавно удалённых файлов. Коммиты удалений отображаются справа, в «Последних событиях» буквами D в красном кружке. Нажимаем на имя удалённого файла левой кнопкой мыши — всё, он восстановлен.

   [image: До восстановления][image: После восстановления]

Недостаток — подвисания при сохранении коммитов после редактирования больших, за 1000 строк, файлов. Пару раз может всплыть окно «Внимание: Сценарий не отвечает»:

[image: Сценарий не отвечает в prose.io]

Поэтому для внесения мелких правок в увесистые файлы данный сервис лучше не использовать.

После коммитов в prose.io не забывайте переносить изменения из репозитория на компьютер командой `git pull`. Спасибо.