# Как добавить вложенные папки в github?

Tags: github

Я новичок в git. Хотел бы выложить верстку макета в github. Есть основная папка **project** в которой есть папки **css**, **fonts**, **img** и сам файл **html**. Подскажите, как выложить папку **project** с входящими в нее файлами. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Эм, почитать про основы Git и, затем, сервиса GitHub?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91877/github-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83?rq=1